# How can I apply YamlDotNet ScalarStyle.SingleQuoted to the string property within a List<string>?

Tags: c#, yaml, yamldotnet

I'm using YamlDotNet to serialize an object like this

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using YamlDotNet.Core;
using YamlDotNet.Serialization;

public class Thing
{
    [YamlMember(ScalarStyle = ScalarStyle.SingleQuoted)]
    public string Name

    [YamlMember(ScalarStyle = ScalarStyle.SingleQuoted)]
    public List<string> Attributes
}
```

I'm serializing the plain string property successfully as expected

```
using YamlDotNet.Serialization;
using YamlDotNet.Serialization.NamingConventions;

var myObject = new Thing
{
    Name = "foo"
    Attributes = new List<string>() { "bar" }
};

var ymlSerializer = new SerializerBuilder()
    .WithNamingConvention(CamelCaseNamingConvention.Instance)
    .ConfigureDefaultValuesHandling(DefaultValuesHandling.OmitEmptyCollections | DefaultValuesHandling.OmitNull)
    .Build();

var serializedYaml = ymlSerializer.Serialize(myObject);
```

Produces yaml:

```
name: 'foo'
attributes:
- bar
```

Expected yaml:

```
name: 'foo'
attributes:
- 'bar'
```

How can I apply the scalar style attribute to a list of a primitive?

Comment: dont forget to close your question by validating the answer, its the way to say thanks to helpers...!!

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a custom converter:

the custom class converter:

```
    public class ThingCategoryYamlTypeConverter : IYamlTypeConverter
    {
        private void WriteContentCategory(IEmitter emitter, object value)
        {
            Thing node;
            node = (Thing)value;

            emitter.Emit(new MappingStart(null, null, false, MappingStyle.Block));

            if (node.Name != null)
            {
                emitter.Emit(new Scalar(null, "name"));
                emitter.Emit(new Scalar(null, null, node.Name, ScalarStyle.SingleQuoted, true, false));
            }

            if (node.Attributes != null)
            {
                this.WriteAttributes(emitter, node);
            }

            emitter.Emit(new MappingEnd());
        }

        private void WriteAttributes(IEmitter emitter, Thing node)
        {
            emitter.Emit(new Scalar(null, "attributes"));
            emitter.Emit(new SequenceStart(null, null, false, SequenceStyle.Block));

            foreach (string child in node.Attributes)
            {
                emitter.Emit(new Scalar(null, null, child, ScalarStyle.SingleQuoted, true, false ));
            }

            emitter.Emit(new SequenceEnd());
        }

        public bool Accepts(Type type)
        {
            return type == typeof(Thing);
        }

        public object ReadYaml(IParser parser, Type type)
        {
            // use for deserialization
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void WriteYaml(IEmitter emitter, object value, Type type)
        {
            this.WriteContentCategory(emitter, value);
        }
    }
```

your class:

```
    public class Thing
    {
        public string Name;

        public List<string> Attributes;
    }
```

call the custom converter

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myObject = new Thing
        {
            Name = "foo",
            Attributes = new List<string> { "bar" }
        };

        var ymlSerializer = new SerializerBuilder()
            .WithTypeConverter(new ThingCategoryYamlTypeConverter())
            .ConfigureDefaultValuesHandling(DefaultValuesHandling.OmitEmptyCollections | DefaultValuesHandling.OmitNull)
            .Build();

        var serializedYaml = ymlSerializer.Serialize(myObject);

    }
```

result:

```
name: 'foo'
attributes:
- 'bar'
```